# Converting from Cylindrical Triple Integral to Spherical Triple Integral

Tags: multivariable-calculus, multiple-integral

Use Spherical Coordinates to Evaluate
$$\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{1}^{2}\int_{0}^{2-r}\frac{r+z}{(r^2+z^2)^{\frac{3}{2}}}r\ dzdrd\theta$$
My Concern: I know how to convert from cylindrical to spherical but, this is my first time to encounter this type of integral such that its radius is starting from $r=1$ to $r=2$

Comment: How would you convert the integral if $r$ went from $0$ to $2$? Start there and try to articulate the problem you are facing when you change the $0$ to a $1$.

Comment: If that's the case, then this given integral will produce two spherical triple integral?

Comment: Have you drawn a picture, say of the cross-section in the $xz$-plane?

Comment: Yes, I already draw it. The solid is like a volcano but it has a hole at the center. That hole is a circle whose radius is 1 unit

Comment: I am not 100% sure but I believe $\theta$ (the angle made with $z$ axis will go from $0$ to $\frac{\pi}{2}$ whereas $\phi$ (angle of the $xy$ plane projection with $x$ axis) goes from $0$ to $2\pi$. Finally $\rho$ (distance from origin) goes from inner surface, the cylinder to the outer conical shaped surface. For the inner cylinder note that if angle made with $z$ axis is $\theta$ then using simple trigonometry and using the radius of this cylinder is $1$ the distance of a point from origin will simply be $\frac{1}{\sin\theta}$. i.e. for given $\theta$, $\rho$ will be $\frac{1}{\sin\theta}$.

Comment: If this is correct then use similar idea to find $\rho$ for outer surface.

Comment: Going by an answer posted, I may be wrong about the range of $\theta$ or $\phi$. But my focus was on finding range of $\rho$ so I didn't visualise else that much.

Comment: I already figure out how to find it but thanks for attempting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think about what each variable becomes when written in spherical coordinates - I will use the ones where $$(x,y,z)=(\rho\sin\varphi \cos\theta, \rho\sin\varphi\sin\theta, \rho\cos\varphi).$$

Clearly $\theta$ is the same, $z=\rho\cos\varphi$ by definition and $r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}=\rho\sin\varphi$. Then the bounds on $\theta$ are the same, and the other ones become $$\begin{cases} 1\leq r\leq 2 \\ 0\leq z\leq 2-r \end{cases} \Rightarrow \begin{cases} 1\leq \rho\sin\varphi\leq 2 \\ 0\leq \rho\cos\varphi\leq 2-\rho\sin\varphi \end{cases} $$ The fact that $z\geq 0$ gives that $0\leq \varphi\leq \pi/2$, thus both $\sin\varphi$ and $\cos\varphi$ are non-negative. From the first we get $$\frac{1}{\sin\varphi}\leq \rho\leq \frac{2}{\sin\varphi}$$ and from the second one $$\rho \leq \frac{2}{\cos\varphi+\sin\varphi}$$ (we have already tackled $0\leq \rho\cos\varphi=z$). Since both must hold, we get that $$\frac{1}{\sin\varphi}\leq \rho\leq \frac{2}{\cos\varphi+\sin\varphi}.\qquad (\star)$$ To finish things off, we have to find the appropriate bounds for $\varphi$. Using $(\star)$ we get that $$\cos\varphi+\sin\varphi\leq 2\sin\varphi\Rightarrow \tan\varphi\geq 1$$ from which we conclude that $\pi/4\leq \varphi\leq \pi/2$.

Notice that this inequality for $\varphi$ can be immediately deduced by drawing a section in the $xz$-plane, since the region is the solid of revolution generated by the triangle with vertices $(1,0)$, $(2,0)$ and $(1,1)$.

Comment: Wow Nice Thank You Actually, we have the same method except to the range of the radius of the sphere. I only got 1/sin(phi) <= p <= 2/sin(phi), thats why I confuse why the answer in wolfram alpha didn't match to my answer.

This is very helpful

Comment: Hi Btw I notice, the bounds for 0<=z<=2-r must be psin(phi) <= p(sin(phi)+cos(phi)) <= 2

Comment: Thanks, I fixed it; in fact we had already used that $0\leq \rho\cos\varphi$.